# OData and Facebook insights

Tags: java, facebook, odata

I am very new do both Facebook insight and to OData. I am new to programing in general so bear with me.
(I just learned about Maven, dependency, JDBC and stuff).

My major problem is that I don't have enough knowledge to even
understand the docs and examples., so...

Looking at odata4j, I do understand that everything starts with:

```
ODataConsumer c = ODataConsumer.create(String serviceRootUri) ;
```

What is the serviceRootUri and how do I find the one that belongs to
Facebook insights?

What I have is:

- registered app with facebook. I already can see the data I want to
  pull (using with odata4j) by going to the insights webpage. I just want to
  automate the pulling of the data with a Java app that will store the
  info into a database.
- I already have an access_token for the app (along with app_key
  and app_secret)

Should serviceRootUri for FB look smth like this?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{app-id-goes-here}/insights?access_token={access-token-goes-here}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OData.org list all the producers and consumers available in the real world for OData as of now. Facebook insights is a producer meaning it exposes a OData service for Facebook Insights.

Have a look at the following URL : http://www.odata.org/producers

Check out the section : Live OData Services.

The Facebook Insights OData Service is avilable at : http://facebook-insights.cloudapp.net/

So thats the OData Service Root URI. That exposes what we call as collections or entitysets. Each collection will be nothing but a rows of data and you can work with them to build a table or whatever visualization you want.

Comment: I actually got examples running, but exactly what I need, the facebook OData doesnt work. It seems it doesnt parse the datetime format very well. I tried setting up a OData consumer both with OData4j and Restlet OData extension. They both fail. The problem is that facebook  is sending a "%3A" instead of a ':' (the encoded "%3A") in their datetime format?  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api for all such matters.